# It is likely that + [past participle]?

Tags: past-participles

A paragraph of a sample IELTS essay about the negative effects of telecommunications technology on people's everyday life starts as follows:

> It is also likely that people have become increasingly accustomed to living in a world that appreciates convenience and inactivity and they do not want to evade those maxims.

Is this sentence poorly designed in that the writer has used **is likely to** coupled with the past participle tense, or it is an accepted usage?

I'm not a native, yet the only way I can justify it is, **it is likely to** was meant, as it were, to connote **it is not unfair to say that**, **it is not far from true to say that** or other phrases along with those lines, or else **likelihood** involves future events and trends, to the best of my knowledge, rather than those having started in the past. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

"It is likely that" simply indicates that what follows these words is seen as a probable situation. Any tense or aspect can follow, for example.:

*It is likely that ...*

*... Luke arrived yesterday.*

*... Emma is seeing Robin again.*

*... John will lose his licence.*

*... the documents have been lost*

Comment: Well, granted, Your examples are immediately understandable, but does it really sit in well in this particular context given that the subsequent sentences of the essay, which I haven't mentioned here, give no sign of likelihood, but show that the writer is sure about people's clear preference for sedentary, inactive lifestyles.

Comment: It is more likely that I, personally would use 'probably' rather than 'it is likely that' in those particular examples. I probably reserve 'It is likely that' for more formal situations such as "It is likely that we will see an increasing burden of chronic disease risk among the poor (*American Journal of Public Health*, Feb 2011). I am afraid I don't see what your second sentence has to do with likelihood.